# String containing backslash

Tags: java

I have a single sign on where I get the username from a string servername\username. Servername can be of any length.I need to get the username for sign on.
I tried replacing the backslash, splitting the string but it is not successful.
Any suggestions how I can extract username from the string.

Comment: You can write your String example here like String value="servername\username" .Do you want the username from the this string.

Answer (score 6):

```
String getUserName(String s) {
  int i = s.indexOf('\\');
  return i == -1 ? s : s.subString(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    String[] input = s.split("\\\\");
    if(input.length != 2 ){
       throw IllegalArguementException();
   }
   String username = input[1];
   String server = input[0];
```

Comment: `String.split` is based on regular expressions. In regexp the `\ ` is a special character and must be escaped. Additionally `\ ` is a special character in string literals. It must be escaped a _second_ time. You have to use `"\\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String userName = input.substring(input.indexOf("\\") + 1);
```